# DIY: Led strip synced with music doesn't work

Tags: led, transistors, music

I made led strip synced with music using this schematic

[image]

I used bd241c instade of tip 31.
When i connect 5V and single LED it works fine but when I put 12V and LED strip it doesnt work.
Can someone help me find where is the problem.

**Edit**: 
I bought LED strip from ebay, [this one](http://m.ebay.com/itm/1M-2M-5M-10M-20M-Colorful-3528-SMD-300-Flexible-LED-lights-strip-/301697570666?nav=SEARCH&varId=600539618390) .

I have 12V,0.4 A adapter and when i connect it directly to strip it glows fine.

**Edit**:
It is bd241c not bc241c.

Comment: What type of LED strip are your trying to use. Can you please update the post with the LED strip specifications

Comment: Datasheet for the transistor where?

Comment: http://www.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheets_pdf/B/D/2/4/BD241.shtml

Answer (score 1):

That circuit requires the music to have peaks above 0.6V, turn the volume up.

If that doesn't work try connecting the base and collector (left and middle transistor pins) if that doesn't light the LED strip, either there's a defective part or there's not enough voltage.

Comment: When i connect base and collector LED strip light up and just stay on, also when i do that i hear giant buzzing

Comment: I am confused because when is at 5V everything works fine, but soon as i hook up 12V it doesnt work

Comment: if you turn off the lights, does it work even a little?

Answer (score 0):

maybe hfe is too low to turn leds on, try using a tip142, it has a hfe of 1000, so leds may turn on even with low volume.
hfe on bd241 is 10, tip31 is around 30, tip142 would be too high but if the led light, you just need a trimpot between p2 jack and tip142 to regulate gain.
remember to put a good heatsink on tip142.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you connecting the audio jack?  Depending on that,[image] you need to place a potentiometer (variable resistor) and a resistor and connect it to the Base (Pin 1) of the TIP31.  Try this.  It works for me.